# Suppose $(X, \mathcal{A})$ is a measurable space, $f$ is a real-valued function, and $\{x:f(x)>r\} \in\mathcal{A}$ for each rational number $r$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, measurable-functions

> Suppose $(X, \mathcal{A})$ is a measurable space, $f$ is a real-valued
>   function, and $\{x:f(x)>r\} \in\mathcal{A}$ for each rational number $r$. Prove that $f$ is measurable.

This proof is fairly straightforward as it is a density argument. I have already written a proof similar to [the approach found here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456177/suppose-x-mathcala-is-a-measurable-space-f-is-a-real-valued-function) The linked proof uses a
converging sequence $r_k\searrow a$ and $\cup_{k=1}^\infty\{x:f(x)>r_k\}=\{x:f(x)>a\}$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ to show that it is measurable. My question is whether it is necessary to use the union or since we can find
some $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ which is arbitrarily close to $a \text{ and }r>a$ would it not just be $\{x:f(x)>r\}=\{x:f(x)>a\}?$ I may be missing something obvious which is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove the desired result (holding for *any* $a \in \Bbb R$), you absolutely need a *countable union* of [superlevel sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set#Sublevel_and_superlevel_sets) $\{f > r\}$(, where $r \in \Bbb Q$).  *Nothing more and nothing less*!

- "nothing more"

  - $\Bbb Q$ is countable and dense in $\Bbb R$
  - A $\sigma$-algebra $\cal A$ is closed under *countable* union/intersection.
  - There's *no* guarantee that $\cal A$ is closed under *arbitrary* union.
- "nothing less"

  - A finite union of superlevel sets $\{f>r\}$ *won't* work since a finite sequence of rational numbers $(r_n)_n$ *won't* take you to an irrational number $a$.

To verify that $\{x \mid f(x) > a\}$ is measurable set, OP asks whether finding an rational number $r$ arbitrarily close to $a$ would work.  Let me illustrative my negative response with a specific example.

## Example pie

Take $a = \pi$.  Fix $\epsilon = 10^{-4}$ before taking an approximation $r = \color{blue}{3.14159}$ for $\pi \approx \color{blue}{3.14159}2654\dots$

To find out $\{f>\pi\}$, $\{f>\color{blue}{3.14159}\}$ would introduce "*undesirable*" elements including (but not limited to) those in $\{x \mid \color{blue}{3.14159}1 \le f \le \color{blue}{3.14159}2\}$: such elements $f(y) \le \color{blue}{3.14159}2 < \pi$ shouldn't belong to $\{f>\pi\}$.

## Formalized idea

As long as you adopt such approximation of $a$ by an arbitrarily close element $r$, you'll introduce "*undesirable*" elements $q$ in either $(a,r)$ or $(r,a)$.  Therefore, no single $\{f>r\}$ can give you $\{f>a\}$, not even a *finite* union $\cup_{k = 1}^n \{f>r_k\} = \left\{f>\min\limits_{k = 1,\dots,n}\{r_k\}\right\}$, where $r_k \in \Bbb Q \forall k$.  You'll need a *countable* union $\cup_{k=1}^\infty\{x:f(x)>r_k\}=\{x:f(x)>a\}$.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I blame my attempt at quitting caffeine for missing what should be obvious. Thank you for the explanation!